# Program created unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have this apt problem. I want to know what program was root cause of this problem.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.43.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
```

As I understand I have installed some 3rd party(not official) program that depends on package libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.43.0-1ubuntu2). Package that I want to install require new version(2.1 not 2). Apt can not install two packages in the same time and I have error. The bug is that some program didn't update its dependencies(din't use new one). Am I correct? How to find this program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have libcurl3-gnutls 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1 from wily-updates installed  but your available  libcurl4-gnutls-dev is the version at wily's release, ie. 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.

So make sure in your sources that wily-security & wily-updates are enabled. If not then enable, update sources & all will be well. If they are already enabled then find a better mirror.

For reference this is the dev package you want - http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily-updates/libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev, yes? It depends on libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.43.0-1ubuntu2), but that version is not available in the software repositories that you have enabled, or its been superseded by a software repository that's offering the newer 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1 version.

Trying disabling all of your extra software repositories, reload in Synaptic, and try and reinstall libcurl4-gnutls-dev using Synaptic. If that works, lock the version of the libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.43.0-1ubuntu2) in Synaptic, then you can re-enable all of your software repositories and reload.

Another method is to locate libcurl3-gnutls in Synaptic, click on the version column, if 7.43.0-1ubuntu2 appears in that list, highlight it, then install it using the "force version" option. Lock it. Then install libcurl4-gnutls-dev, and all dependencies should be met.

Cheers, Al